# How can I mock a static extension method in dbContext

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to create a test to mock the execution the stored procedure. I have a static class called `LoadStoredProcedure` this create a dbCommand

```
public static DbCommand LoadStoredProc(this DbContext context, string storedProcName, bool prependDefaultSchema = true, short commandTimeout = 30)
{
    var cmd = context.Database?.GetDbConnection()?.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;

    if (prependDefaultSchema)
    {
        var schemaName = context.Model.GetDefaultSchema();

        if (schemaName != null)
        {
            storedProcName = $"{schemaName}.{storedProcName}";
        }
    }

    cmd.CommandText = storedProcName;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    return cmd;
}
```

but this is an static method, and here i have a mock of the dbContext

```
public static async Task<BTContext> getBtContextForStoreProcedure()
{
    try
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BTContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Options;

        Mock<BTContext> context = new Mock<BTContext>(options);

        List<responseStored> list = new()
        {
            new responseStored() {
                p_return_value=new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = "@p_servicable", Value = 10 }
            }
        };

        var optionss = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BTContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;
        var dbContextToMock = new BTContext(options);

        Mock<DbContext> mocked = new();

        var mockedDbContext = new MockedDbContextBuilder<BTContext>().UseDbContext(dbContextToMock).UseConstructorWithParameters(optionss).MockedDbContext;

        /*var another = mockedDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
        context.Setup(s =>s.Database.GetDbConnection()).Returns(another);*/

        /*mocked.Setup(s => s.LoadStoredProc(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<short>())).Returns;*/

        mocked.Setup(s => s.LoadStoredProc(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<short>()).
        WithSqlParam(It.IsAny<List<MySqlParameter>>()).ExecuteStoredProcAsync<responseStored>()).ReturnsAsync(list);

        return context.Object;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

but return this error

> unsupported expression extension methods may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot mock a static method, and so you cannot mock an extension method either.

One way to do this is to change `LoadStoredProc` into a virtual method of a factory class (or an interface). Or you live with the fact and create Setup's for the implementation of the `LoadStoredProc` method. That would mean you would create an expectation for the `Database` property with something like `mocked.Setup(x => x.Database).Returns(something)`.